# Laravel list music genres with sub model popularity

Tags: mysql, laravel, model

I have 4 tables:

1. `MusicGenre`
2. `Artist`
3. `Song`
4. `SongInfo`

`weekly_hit` is a column on the `SongInfo` table.

`MusicGenre` is connected to `Artist` like this:

```
public function artists()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Artist\ArtistInfo','genre_id','id');
}
```

`Artist` is connected to `Song` like this:

```
public function songs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Song\Songs','artist_id');
}
```

And `Song` is connected to `SongInfo` like this:

```
public function info()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Song\SongsInfo','song_id','id');
}
```

There is a no problem querying the table.

My problem is that I want to get the best music genres using `weekly_hit` in `SongInfo` table.

Edit:

I resolved that problem with raw code

```
"select music_genres.*, 
sum(distinct song_info.weekly_hit) as song_popularity

from `music_genres` 

left join `artist_info` on
`music_genres`.`id` = `artist_info`.`genre_id`

left join songs on 
artist_info.artist_id = songs.artist_id

left join songs_info on 
songs.id = songs_info.song_id

group by music_genres.name

order by song_popularity DESC

limit 5
```

But, I can't get songs. I want to get 5 song ordered by weekly_hit in songs_info  table from all returned music genres.

Guys i still searching a solution?

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Sounds like you need to loop over `Songs` and get each song's `song_id`, then query each `SongInfo` to look up and record the `weekly_hit` along with the `song_id` in a temporary place.  Then you can sort the `song_id`s by `weekly_hit`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use Eloquent's hasManyThrough() relation to reach that deep in the relationship chain.